# How to detect when the user scrolls the page in different sizes

Tags: jquery, function, scroll, width

I need a function to detect when the user scroll the page in small and normal widths.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on("load resize", function () {
        if ($(window).width() > 752) {
            alert("Desktop version");
            $(this).scroll(function () {                   
                alert("Scrolled in desktop version");
            });
        }
        else {
            alert("Mobile function");
            $(this).scroll(function () {
                alert("Scrolled in mobile version");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```css
div{
    background-color:blue;
    height:2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>page</div>
```

Comment: What is the issue with your current code?

Comment: The function isn't working as i need, when the user scrools in desktop or in mobile version, or the function don't runs or all the functions(desktop and mobile) runs.

Comment: Your code works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/z04uj38t/1/ - open your console to see

Comment: this appears when you scroll in desktop version:

Comment: 19(index):37 Scrolled in mobile version
14(index):31 Scrolled in desktop version
19(index):37 Scrolled in mobile version ...

Comment: Ah ok, see my answer for an explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your window width logic inside the scroll event. Currently you are attaching multiple scroll events when the screen is resized.

```js
$(window).on("load resize", function () {
  $(this).scroll(function () {      
    if ($(window).width() > 752) {
      console.log("Scrolled in desktop version");
    }
    else {
      console.log("Scrolled in mobile version");
    }
  });    
});
```

```css
div{
    background-color:blue;
    height:2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```